# When using tkinter, how can I save a variable for future use?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I save the variable 'name' for future use? I want to call on this variable later in the code, but for some reason I get this error: "NameError: name 'name' is not defined"

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = [
"Name 1",
"Name 2",
"Name 3"
]

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

def ok():
    name =variable.get()
    print (name)
    master.destroy()

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Make it a global variable.

Comment: Where are you trying to refer to it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean "for future use" in the same module ? If yes, you just need to make it a global variable as in:

```
    def ok():
        global name
        name = variable.get()
```